# Lodash Clone Array vs Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, clone

I was wondering if anyone knows whether the spread operator

```
cosnt newArray = [...oldArray];
```

makes the lodash method

```
const newArray = _.clone(oldArray);
```

obsolete?

Or more importantly if either method is more efficient?

*Note this is a shallow clone, just want object references in a new array.

Thank you!

Comment: Not any more obsolete than `newArray = oldArray.slice()` or `newArray = oldArray.concat()` already did.

Comment: _.clone does a LOT more than just clone an array. If you just want to clone an array and that's it, spread operator is the way to go. If you're cloning thousands of arrays that each contain thousands of elements (or hundreds of arrays on every keystroke), at that point you should probably look at performance.

Comment: Adam, could you expand on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `clone` is faster than the spread operator: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/81691 .

However, as [javascript in an expensive resource to process](https://medium.com/dev-channel/the-cost-of-javascript-84009f51e99e), it's probably not a good idea to add a library to do what vanilla js can do perfectly well.

Comment: Hey, awesome. I never knew about that tool either. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder on what machine/browser combination you tested this, if I retry your benchmark the spread operator is considerably faster on my machine (iMac/Safari) see: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6250/2/spread-operator-vs-lodash

Comment: I'm guessing there have been updates to JS that improved the performance of the spread operator since it was originally reported as slower.

Answer (score 1):

`_.clone` can be used on many things *other* than arrays:

> This method is loosely based on the structured clone algorithm and supports cloning arrays, array buffers, booleans, date objects, maps, numbers, Object objects, regexes, sets, strings, symbols, and typed arrays. The own enumerable properties of arguments objects are cloned as plain objects. An empty object is returned for uncloneable values such as error objects, functions, DOM nodes, and WeakMaps.

In contrast, spread syntax in the context of an array will only work on *iterable* objects (such as arrays, and certain other collections that have a `Symbol.iterator` property), and will only produce plain arrays. Many things can be called with `_.clone` to shallow clone them that can't be done with array spread - such as plain objects.

(There is such thing as object spread which can shallow copy objects, but the syntax is *pretty* new)

Another thing to consider is browser compatibility - spread syntax requires ES6 support, whereas the invocation of a library method `_.clone` does not.

Comment: the OP specifically stated only shallowly cloning an array was required.